# The relationship between consistency and completeness

Tags: logic, set-theory

Let T be a formal system that interprets arithmetic. Let A be a large cardinal axiom.

Question: If we can prove the consistency of T within the system (T + A), does it imply that we can also prove the completeness of T within the same system? That is for any sentence $\delta$ that is definable in T, we can also decide whether or not $\delta$ is true in the system?

Comment: Consider, for instance, $T=\mathsf{ZFC}$ and $A=\operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$. Clearly $T+A$ proves the consistency of $T$, but $T$ is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

No.  "Completeness" and "consistency" are, in effect, opposites. The truth of one does not imply the other.  There exist systems of axioms that are "complete" but not "consistent" and there exist systems of axioms that are "consistent" but not "complete".

Comment: (That's an ugly version of completeness. I would include consistency as part of the requirements of complete theories.)

Comment: ""Completeness" and "consistency" are, in effect, opposites." I think that's pretty misleading - lots of theories are both complete and consistent, even really simple ones (e.g. the theory of [real closed fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field#Model_theory:_decidability_and_quantifier_elimination)).